# how to implement modulate in customRollingFileAppender using log4j version 1 to generate log file if no logger is getting called

Tags: java, log4j

I want to generate log files every 15mins even if no log event is triggered. i have to use only log4j version 1.2.7. I know using log4j 2 we can do this, but i want to implement modulate in my customRollingFileAppender.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any workaround in Log4j for this but alternatively in Java you can implement TimerTask to generate a log in your customRollingFileAppender.

Sample code provided below

```
int MINUTES = 10; // The delay in minutes
Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() { // Function runs every MINUTES minutes.
        // Run the code you want here
        CLASSB.funcb(); // If the function you wanted was static
    }
 }, 0, 1000 * 60 * MINUTES);
    // 1000 milliseconds in a second * 60 per minute * the MINUTES variable.
```

Comment: i'm able to generate log every 15mins, but what i want is in our case after 12pm no user activity will happen at that no log will trigger and log file will not generate, it will wait till another log event tirggered. In this case i want empty log files also every 15mins.